# Android Button properties change everytime the app runs

Tags: android, android-layout, button

In Android is there a way of setting up a button such that every time I run the program the button has different properties?

i.e. A button having a different colour background every time I run the program

Comment: you create an array containing color values and pick random value from array,then set the background color of button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an activity you find your button with

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.myButtonId);
```

and set it's background color like this

```
int color = // generate some random color
btn.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Random() in order to set background color to button .

For Example:

```
  int[] color={Color.RED,Color.BLACK,Color.GREEN};

  onCreate()
  {
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    Random random=new Random();

    b.setBackgroundColor(color[random.nextInt(3)]);

  }
```